# mysql SELECT EXISTS on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Have tables: person,person_ip

Both tables have `pid` column as a primary key, in table `person` there is column `state_id`, in table `person_ip` there is column `ip`.

Want to discover if specified IP address is assigned to person with `state_id` is not equal to `2`. But always got result `1`, even if `state_id` is `0`, `1` or `2`. Always got `0` only if ip address is not listed at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT person_ip.PID
    FROM person_ip,person
    WHERE person.PID=person_ip.PID
        AND person.state_id NOT IN (2)
        AND person_ip.ip='10.11.12.13'
)
```

Comment: Current query should tell if anyone has that IP with state not 2, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: provide some data sample or sqlfiddle would be perfect

Comment: Addendum: Same IP address could reside in multiple rows of 'person_ip' table with different 'PID's. Does this information change situation?

Comment: depends. if it is assigned to someone with state 2, and someone else with not state 2, do you want to include it as a result?

Comment: not, I am only interested in combination: ip_address - state_id !=2

Comment: @user2956477 i see. i've amended my answer below to what i think you need

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a simple `join`.. unless i'm missing something

```
select person.*
  from person
    inner join person_ip
      on person.pid = person_ip.pid
  where person.state_id <> 2
    and person_ip.ip_address = '10.0.0.1'
```

If you want to exclude the ip_address if it has been assigned to any user with state = 2, even if it has also been assigned to a user without state = 2, then try:

```
select max(i)
  from (
    select *
      from (
        select 1 as i
          from dual
          where not exists (
            select 1
              from person p
                inner join person_ip pi
                  on p.pid = pi.pid
              where p.state_id = 2
                and pi.ip_address = '10.0.0.1'
          )
      ) q
    union 
    select 0
  ) qq
```

(dual is a system table that can be used as a sort of stub table)

[here's a fiddle showing both versions](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7f43/1)

**update after some actual sleep**

Okay, so the above query is a little.. out there.  Back in the real world, this one is probably more appropriate:

```
  select count(case when p1.state_id = 2 then 1 end) 
    from person p1
      inner join person_ip pi1
        on p1.pid = pi1.pid
    where pi1.ip_address = '10.0.0.1'
    group by pi1.ip_address;
```

This will return 1 or more if your ip_address has been used by someone with a state_id of 2, and 0 if it has never been used by someone with a state_id of 2.

It will return nothing if the ip has never been used.

[this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/662b4/10) has all three of the above queries.

Comment: I would move `AND person_ip.ip_address = '10.0.0.1'` to `ON` clause to optimize performance

Comment: @alex irrelevant change, the optimiser treats it exactly the same as this query, go ahead and try it

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0,1,0)
FROM person
INNER JOIN person_ip
  ON person.pid = person_ip.pid
  AND person_ip.ip_address = '10.0.0.1'
WHERE person.state_id <> 2
```